# Relative Layout is not allowed inside Toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-relativelayout

I'm facing strange warning, trying to customize the Toolbar appearance. I put `RelativeLayout` inside `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` to reorganize `Toolbar`. Everything works and appears as expected on both emulator and device. The only problem is the annoying warning that appears in .xml file as seen below:

[image: screenshot of the warning]

The question is what is the actual problem, how can it harm my application and how can I solve this warning. As I know `Toolbar` behaves as `ViewGroup`, why `RelativeLayout` is not allowed to be it's child?
Thanks.

Comment: @VivekMishra you are wrong. Toolbar element is a ViewGroup and of course it can host child views

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Toolbar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html) extends from [`ViewGroup`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) and [`RelativeLayout's`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) too.

I've tried that on `Android Studio 1.5.1` and i couldn't see that problem.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/toolBarTv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                    android:textSize="18dp">
                </RelativeLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

You should be able to update your `Android Studio` to the last version or checking if you are using outdated `Platform`, then you need to just update that `Platform` to the last version.

And then it won't show up.or perhaps it will fixed in the next update.

Comment: The things is, `1.5.1` is the latest version from stable channel.try to update  and reinvalidate the cache and restart it, then it should work.